# retrieve hash bang / shebang from given script file

Tags: python, shell, shebang

Is there a way to retrieve the path to the interpreter a UNIX shell would use for a given script? (preferably in a Python API or as shell command)?

To be used like this:

```
$ get_bang ./myscript.py
/usr/bin/python3
```

Of course I could extract it manually using RE but I'm sure in real world that's more complicated than just handling the first line and I don't want to re-invent the wheel..

The reason I need this is I want to call the script from inside another script and I want to add parameters to the interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it isn't more complicated than reading (the first word) of the first line.

Try putting the shebang on the second line (or even just putting a space before the `#`) and see what happens.

Also see http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/ and http://homepages.cwi.nl/~aeb/std/hashexclam-1.html for more than you've ever wanted to know about the shebang feature.

Answer (score 2):

Many ways - for example:

```
sed -n '1s/^#!//p' filename
```

prints for example

```
/bin/sh
```

or (if multiword)

```
/usr/bin/env perl
```

or nothing, if here isn't shebang

Comment: Minor improvements: `sed -n '1{s/^#![[:blank:]]*//p;q}' filename`